# Capture error message when selenium test fails

Tags: c#, selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

There is a way to get the Selelium error message when an Assert fails, or the webdriver is unable to find the element, or similar causes? The only solution that I found to manage it is use a try/catch in all my test methods, but I hope there is a better way.

I've trying to save log messages when a test pass with success or when it fails, so if it fails I want to get the error message to save it in the log. Also, I'm Using C# with Microsoft UnitTestFramework and the Selenium WebDriver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly its not the best solutions... but...

1. you can use framework-wrapper around selenium and there will be try/catch in all needed places
2. You can wrap by ONE single try/catch and check for exact errors that was thrown by selenium library and log it.
   I mean you don't need to catch (Exception), you need to catch

> ```
>  catch (Selenium.SeleniumException se)
>     {
>     /// your logging of se
>     }
> ```

Comment: How do you put a "framework-wrapper around selenium"?

Comment: @JeffC I mean your own group of methods that wrapping selenium objects.
As example I build my own framework-wrapper and now searching of elements have another syntax: browser.Page.Elem(By.Xpath(".//someXPath"), AwaitFor.Visible(1500)).AsInput().Text = "some Text that must be in this input";  -- And in this example I have a really lot of code hidden behind, also there is included try/catches

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to implement this for a TestSuite?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log the Selenium exceptions, you need to catch them. I would suggest you put a try/catch around your test call like below.

```
try
{
    Test1();
}
```

in your catch, you would catch whatever exceptions you want to log and then write the exception message to the log. You can google C# try/catch to get some pointers on how to best do this, if needed.